# response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None : when more than two query params are passed

Tags: django-rest-framework, query-string, x-frame-options

I'm trying to make a  GET API call through DRF.

My URL looks like this:
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/patha/pathb/pathc/pathd/cd7701b?name=IT&size=20&workflow=rv

But It's producing an error:

```
   if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

but when I'm just sending two query params:

```
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/patha/pathb/pathc/pathd/cd007b?name=IT&size=20
```

or, any combination of two params out of those three it's reaching the view method.

My view Method looks like this:

```
 class MyRtList(generics.ListAPIView, customMixin):
 ...
 # Here I'd like to use all three inputs:
 # cd007b
 # `name` and `size`
```

And urls.py:

```
    url(r'patha/pathb/pathc/(?P<name>[^/]+)?$',views.MyRtList.as_view()),
```

I was going through Doc. example shown with param1 and param2.
Is it maximum to use two query param? 
Is it forbidden to use mixed data like cd007b and query param?
Because it's getting stuck with 3 params but not with 2 params.

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. No DRF is involved. I have a test with django test client that fails this way.

Comment: Ok, so in my case the issue was, that I was trying to return a mocked response from the `responses` module in django view. The reason for this was that I was trying to forward a response from `requests.get` via the django.view. The solution was to create a new response with the same content/status...

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, I am having the same issue @smido

Comment: @Djangodev if you can describe your problem, i can try

Comment: @smido I am getting the same, I need the solution

Comment: @Djangodev The solution is as described. I don't know your exact situation so you have to figure out to apply it.

Comment: Are you trying to use return reverse('url-name'), If Yes then just change it to return redirect('url-name') and it should work.

Comment: I forgot to add `render` at the views.py. My view needs to `return render(...)`, I wrote: `return (...)`, then you get the error if you forgot to add **render**.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the solution in my case

If you forgot to add render to your view in ***views.py*** then make sure to add `render`

***views.py***

*Before:*

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def test1(request):
    kontext = {}

    # This will give error
    return (request, 'appName/test1.html', kontext)
```

---

*After:*

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def test1(request):
    kontext = {}

    return render(request, 'appName/test1.html', kontext)
```